# How do I handle errors in passport.deserializeUser()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I've got Express and Passport configured like so:

```
var express = require("express");
var site = express();
var flash = require("connect-flash");
var passport = require("passport");

site.use(require("cookie-parser")());
site.use(require("body-parser").urlencoded({extended:false}));
site.use(require("express-session")(...));
site.use(flash());
site.use(passport.initialize());
site.use(passport.session());
```

I've got a pretty stock implementation of `deserializeUser` (I'm using `local` authentication backed by MySQL via Bookshelf):

```
var db = require("./database.js"); // exports models e.g. db.User

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.User.findById(id).then(function (user) {
        done(null, user);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        done(err, null);
    });
});
```

I'm running in to the following specific problem: When a logged-in user is deleted from the database (happens when e.g. a site administrator deletes the user), the deserialization fails, as expected, with a `CustomError("EmptyResponse")` from Bookshelf. However, I don't know how to handle it; `done(err, null)` ultimately just causes the error message and stack trace to get sent back as HTML to the client.

The question is: **How can I provide custom, graceful error handling from `deserializeUser` on a failure?**

Now, if it simplifies things, I could add `{require:false}` to the `db.User.findById` call to give me a `null` user instead of an error, but I still don't know how to handle it (and also I still do need to handle error objects e.g. if the database server is down and there's a connection error).

The action I want to take on failure is to redirect the user back to the login page, potentially with a descriptive flash message, but I don't have any access to the request/response in `deserializeUser` and I'm not sure how to communicate back.

Comment: Can you just check for the message in the error (`err.message`) and send back some custom response that looks nice for the user? (In the `catch` callback)

Comment: @JoshBeam That's what I *want* to do, but how do I access the response object from there? It's not passed as a parameter to `deserializeUser`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out one solution. Errors here can be handled in an Express middleware error-handler. So, for example:

```
// Note: Must be used *after* passport middleware.
site.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle deserialization errors here.
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

One important caveat though is if deserialization failed non-recoverably, *all* routes accessed through passport (even ones that don't require authentication) will continue to fail, *which most likely also includes your login and logout endpoints, thus permanently breaking access until the user clears their cookies*. So you have to force a logout, it's the only real way to recover:

```
site.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err) {
        req.logout(); // So deserialization won't continue to fail.
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Further building on that, in my case I wanted to redirect back to the login page with a flash message. But you have to be careful: If an error occurs on the login page itself you need to avoid infinite redirects, so:

```
site.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err) {
        req.logout();
        if (req.originalUrl == "/loginpage") {
            next(); // never redirect login page to itself
        } else {
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            res.redirect("/loginpage");
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

And of course you probably want to only do this for `CustomError("EmptyResponse")`, or even redo the error handling in your deserialize implementation to have it throw your own more specific error.

Kind of a weird approach, but seems to get the job done. Open to cleaner suggestions.

Comment: Well done for figuring out an elegant solution. I'm curious why there is no official recipe for this flow. Though this is a more than valid approach, I have a feeling something is missing here. Why is it that passport assumes that the client is expecting a standard 500 error with a stack trace? Is this somehow "not supposed to happen" in production?

Comment: I know it's for a long time ago, but helped me get out of a serious problem. Thank you for that. Just think the second code needs a next() after logout too. otherwise you'll be stuck with no response.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Passport docs "Configure" section](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure), they show the ability to send a specific message:

```
return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
```

The above example is in their docs, but in your case, you could do something like:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.User.findById(id).then(function (user) {
        done(null, user);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        done(err, null, { message: 'User does not exist' });
    });
});
```

Comment: No, that's not quite right. That form of `done` is only valid in the context of the authentication strategy (the docs example is when configuring a strategy), and the flash message parameter ends up being made available to the rest of the Express chain. It has no effect in `deserializeUser`, where `done(err, ...)` causes the chain to stop immediately and the full error message and stack trace to just sent back to the client. No more handlers execute, and I don't have any opportunity to do anything with the response.